# JTable enter key actions

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keyevent, enter

I am developing an application using `JTable` for inventory management.

The action is, by typing the item code in a `JTextField` and by pressing enter key, the details of that code should come to `JTable`. And there I have to type the quantity and press enter to calculate the amount.

But now by giving item code the details come to the `JTable`, and I can type the quantity, but there by pressing enter key `JTable` focus goes to the next row and no calculation is being done.  I am using MySQL and Java in Netbeans.

I found some code.  This code you given earlier for this problem

```
private void createKeybindings(JTable table) {
    table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
    table.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        }
    });
}
```

But I have no clear idea about this code.

- Please explain where to add this code or there are any other codes to do this.
- Please tell me step by step where i put this code in Netbeans IDE (I follow this link https://web.archive.org/web/20120626114430/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html, but I can't understand it).

Thank you...

Comment: Okay, where are you typing the quantity?  Into the table itself? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  I'm not sure a key binding is the appropriate solution to your problem

Comment: quantity is typing in the jTable cell,I put some calculations to jTable keyevent.                                                                        if(evt.getKeyCode()==10){
            itemtotal();
                        } ,but when i press enter it will change row selection

Comment: If the quantity is been managed by the `TableModel`, then when the cell is update, you should be calculating the total there

Comment: no no,i just want to disable defult enter key event in jTable

Comment: Fine, but I think it's the wrong way to achieve what you are trying to do.  The `TableModel` is responsible for managing the data which is made available to the `JTable`, messing with the default navigation mechanisms of the table could really annoy users

Comment: You should not be using magic numbers - "10" is a magic number. Better yet, you should not even be using a KeyListener with the table or your editor. The `TableModel` is the way to go.

Comment: Please explain how to use tablemodel to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three columns like Quantity, Price, Amount then you could override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel with code like:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(value, row, column);

    if (column == 0 || column == 1)
    {
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        int quantity = ((Integer)model.getValueAt(row, 0)).intValue();
        double price = ((Double)model.getValueAt(row, 1)).doubleValue();
        Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
        model.setValueAt(value, row, 2);
    }
}
```